# Python For loops in While loop, starting for loop with a specific value

Tags: python, variables, for-loop, while-loop, initialization

I've started learning Python a few days ago and I ran into a program while coding something.

Here's what I want to do using C++ code

```
number = SOME_NUMBER;
while(1) {
    for(int i=number; i<sizeOfArray; i++) {
        // do something
    }
    number = 0;
}
```

Basically, for the very first iteration of my for loop, I want to start i at number.
Then for every other time i go through the for loop, I want to start it at 0.

My kind of hacky idea that I can think of right now is to do something like:

```
number = SOME_NUMBER
for i in range(0, len(array)):
    if i != number:
        continue
    // do something

while True:
    for i in range(0, len(array)):
        // do something
```

Is this the best way or is there a better way?

Comment: This depends on what `// do something` is.

Comment: Looping through lists by index makes no sense in Python, it is slow and doesn't read well - loop over the values instead.

Comment: Umm - you've already got answers - but I would write `for(;;)` instead of `while(1)` in your C++ code - I believe that's the way to write "forever"...

Comment: if you have an answer that solves your issue, you can mark is as accepted.

Answer (score 7):

what is the problem with this?

```
starting_num = SOME_NUMBER
while True:
    for i in xrange(starting_num, len(array)):
        # do code
    starting_num = 0
```

it does exactly what you want.

however, i think there are better ways to do things especially if the solution seems "hacky".

if you gave an idea of what you wanted to do, maybe there is a better way

Comment: Oh that is true, I never thought about putting starting_num right in xrange.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why you couldn't just do the same thing you are in C:

```
number = SOME_NUMBER
while True:
    for i in range(number, len(array)):
        # do something
    number = 0
```

BTW, depending on which version of Python you're using, `xrange` may be preferable over `range`.  In Python 2.x, `range` will produce an actual list of all the numbers.  `xrange` will produce an iterator, and consumes far less memory when the range is large.

Comment: what is the difference between xrange and range?

Comment: I updated my answer, but `xrange` will produce an iterator, while `range` will produce a list.  In Python 3, `range` produces an iterator.

Comment: if the range is really small though, 2-4, is it still better to use xrange?

Answer (score 1):

In Python, stepping over a collection in the traditional sense is not ideal. The ability to loop - to iterate - over an object is controlled by the object, so you don't need to manually step through counters as you would in the `for` loop in C++.

As I understand it, what you are trying to do here is execute the same piece of code over each item in a `list` (there are no *arrays* in Python), a multiple number of times.

To do that:

```
def whatever_function(foo):
   # some code here that works on each item on the list
   # foo is an item of the list

while True:
   map(whatever_function, some_list)
```

Comment: hmm well my program is a card game that just looks through each person's turn.

Comment: originally, I had it so that it was
while game is still running:
  for player in players:
     do all this

but i changed it to indexes so I could keep track of what player "last made a play" by just storing the player index.

a round could last through several for loops
and players could pass on their turn.  If on one iteration of a for loop, the person turned out to have made a move prior (by changing if the i == last_played_moved_index)

It means everyone passed on their turn.

then i'd reset everything so that a fresh round is started